# Dropdown is not working on website (css display tags)

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this for quite a while, and cannot seem to find why my dropdown menu is not working. After searching many online forums and asking friends, I have no answer. I just want the dropdown to work. I cannot seem to make the .dropdown_trigger class make the .dropdown class hide, or reappear. Any help would be very much appreciated. Linked below are the pages.

Thanks,

Alex

***[Index Page](http://drssit.org/portfolio/arehart70/index.html)***  ***[CSS File](http://drssit.org/portfolio/arehart70/StyleSheet/globalstylesheet.css)***

Comment: Because links can sometimes go down, please remember to post relevant code snippets of where the problem is and what the fix was after you get your answer. Some poor developer in the future may have the same problem as you in the near future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the html page provided in the "Index Page" link, there is only one element with the "dropdown" class, and it's empty. It's not clear what your code is trying to show or hide.

```
<div class="dropdown"></div>
```

The "dropdown_trigger" class is located in a table header element:

```
<th>
  <a href="AArehartProjects.html" class="dropdown_trigger">PROJECTS</a>
</th>
```

By inspection, there does not appear to be any javascript to trigger any behavior. It does not show up in Source in the Chrome Inspector. Normally, this would be done with JS to use .show() or .hide(), for example if you had jQuery (there are other ways). Or are you trying to create this without JS at all? Are you trying to create dropdown menus with only CSS?

If so, please check this tutorial out:

- https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

The key part is here:

```
ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

By creating a CSS rule to change the visibility, the dropdown menu can be shown. However, there does not appear to be any HTML content to show in the current linked page you provided. That `div` is empty.